# Can't flash ClockwordMod onto Verizon GS4

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, rom-manager

I just got a warrentied Galaxy S4 (running VRUEMK2) and am trying to install ClockwordMod and CyanogenMod onto it like I had on my previous GS4. I rooted it, installed ROM Manager, and flashed ClockWorkMod Touch 6.0.4.4, and ROM Manager shows that it is in fact installed (top of the app shows current recovery as ClockworkMod 6.0.4.4). Problem is, when I reboot into recovery, I still see the stock Samsung boot loader. I think this is the root cause that is preventing me from being able to install CyanogenMod.

Tried installing it manually as well through [here](http://theblogoftechnology.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/install-clockworkmod-recovery-without-rom-manager/), but didn't do anything.

Any ideas? I've scoured most threads on multiple message boards and still haven't figured out what the issue is.

Comment: ROM Manager is crap. Try flashing the recovery using Flashify. Then, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also, make sure to flash the latest recovery.

Comment: Tried using Flashify to flash ClockworkMod 6.0.4.4 Touch. It worked, but now after rebooting the phone I get an error "System software not authorized by Verizon..." and I can't boot the OS. I'm googling around to see how to fix this, but in the meantime help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you've flashed CWM Touch via Flashify, have you tried booting into recovery mode? Then, flashing CM and GAPPS?

Comment: It's not letting me boot into recovery mode. The only screen I get is the Verizon unauthorized screen, and I can't get anywhere from there.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you have a locked bootloader. You'll have to unlock that first. See if this helps: http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-Root-and-Unlock-your-Verizon-Samsung-Galaxy-S4_id43539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VRUEMK2 - is not Bootloader unlocked. So no CWM and custom ROMS for this. You only have root via SafeRoot method. There isn't a known bootloader unlock yet for the past 2 or 3 OTA releases.

Comment: Seems I figured this out the hard way, unfortunately. Hopefully an unlock gets figured out soon!